# Protobuf, import error after compilation in python3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers

Directory structure:

```
Application/
   proto/
     payload.proto
     lab_account.proto
     public_trail.proto
   protocompiled/
     payload_pb2.py
     lab_account_pb2.py
```

Contents of the payload.proto

```
syntax = "proto3";
import "lab_account.proto";
import "public_trail.proto";
```

if I compile my payload.proto file, with command .

```
 Application⟫ protoc --proto_path=./proto --python_out=./protocompiled payload.proto
```

The compiled payload_pb2.py doest have the required imports. It has wrong import statement like this.

```
 import lab_account_pb2 as lab__account__pb2
 import public_trail_pb2 as public__trail__pb2
```

instead of this;

```
 import protocompiled.lab_account_pb2 as lab__account__pb2
 import protocompiled.public_trail_pb2 as public__trail__pb2
```

Also referred, https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/1491 but couldnt solve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

There is an open [issue 5374](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/5374) in protobuf github regarding this problem.

Until it is resolved, I use the following workaround: after `protoc` run a sed script (works at least for GNU `sed`) which will add relative imports.

```sh
protoc $PATH/*.proto --python_out=$PROTOC_OUTDIR
sed -i $PROTOC_OUTDIR/*_pb2.py -e 's/^import [^ ]*_pb2/from . \0/'
```

But this works only when all files are in the same directory. More complex script will be required to handle files spread over multiple directories.

Comment: Nice workaround, now I really wonder why I haven't tought about this myself :)